# Testing Kubernetes using minikube on MacOS

Tags: macos, testing, kubernetes, deployment, minikube

I have a simple REST app I want to deploy into kubernetes. *Before* I deploy into a cloud provider environment, I want to test out locally using `minikube`. Here's my setup:

```yaml
---
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: example
  spec:
    replicas: 3
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        name: example
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: example
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: application
          image: 1ijk/example
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000

---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    name: example
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
    selector:
      name: example
```

and how I'm invoking it

```
$ minikube start --driver=hyperkit
[ output omitted ]
$ kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
deployment.apps/example created
ingress.extensions/example-ingress created
$ kubectl get service example
NAME           TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
example        NodePort   10.100.198.224   <none>        3000:32275/TCP   4s
minikube service example --url
http://192.168.64.2:32275
$ minikube service example
|-----------|---------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |  NAME   | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|---------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | example | http/80     | http://192.168.64.2:31726 |
|-----------|---------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Opening service default/example in default browser...
```

However the browser is unable to connect. I've verified the application binary and its container image both function properly. I seem to be missing a piece of the kubernetes setup on minikube, and all the tutorials I've seen assume a cloud deployment with the `LoadBalancer` service type.

What can I do to test this simple kubernetes application locally using `minikube`?

---

#### updates

here's the service description

```
$ kubectl describe service example
Name:                     example
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"example","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http","...
Selector:                 name=example
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.107.95.114
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31726/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

after bypassing the yml file and using the cli to create the deployment and service like so

```
kubectl create deployment example --image=1ijk/example
kubectl expose deployment example --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=3000
```

I get the service set like so

```
$ kubectl describe service example
Name:                     example
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=example
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=example
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.100.117.7
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31683/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.10:3000,172.17.0.5:3000,172.17.0.7:3000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

and same result

#### final update: see comments guiding the debug process in the answer below

The problem was *not* with the kubernetes -- it was with my app! I made the mistake of binding the go server to `"127.0.0.1:3000"` instead of `":3000"` :faceplam:. Binding to the port without specifying IP allows the application server to be accessible on all the containers networking interfaces :)

Comment: add output of kubectl describe  svc example

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu I've edited the post to include the service description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoints of the service is not showing POD IPs.You need to expose pods via a LoadBalancer type service. Instead of using a service yaml use below command.

```
kubectl expose deployment example --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=3000
```

And then you can get the url via below command and use it browser to access the  application.

```
minikube service example
```

Edit:

The go app had a hard-coded value for address which was bound to `127.0.0.1`.Because of the hardcoding it was not accessible from inside the cluster as well which was verified by curl to `10.100.117.7:3000` from another pod on the cluster.Removing that hardcoding solved the problem.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/

Comment: thanks. giving this a try now. another piece of the documentation led me to believe that _wasn't_ possible locally, but I now see this sentence in the link you provided: "On Minikube, the LoadBalancer type makes the Service accessible through the minikube service command."

Comment: this isn't working for me -- same result as in the original post

Comment: can you verify if the pods are up and running?

Comment: from your previous output I see the endpoints of service is empty which is the problem

Comment: the endpoints are now set following the cli commands with same result in the browser / curl

Comment: is this a nodejs app? can you curl to 10.100.117.7:3000 from inside another pod...you can us exec to get into another pod? what url are you giving in the browser?

Comment: it's a go app -- but, oh my, you know what I did? I had a hard-coded value for address which bound to `127.0.0.1`. Drop that, and it'll bind correctly in the container. curling from inside another pod was the right advice to identify this problem. Thank you!

Comment: would you kindly place the debug process and the mistake found in this answer please? thank you very much for your help

Comment: I added it in the answer..check it out